# Read XML Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My XML recorded as a field my SQL database, I am trying to read some of the values from the XML. For example, I have try following code to get the ItemID from XML, but no result were returned.

```
SELECT 
      N.C.value('itemId[1]', 'int') ItemId

  FROM [isalesystemdb].[dbo].[Test_eBay_Keyword_Transaction] 
  cross apply rawdata.nodes('/findItemsByKeywordsResponse/SearchResult/item') N(C)
```

Thank you for your help!
here are the XML '

```
<findItemsByKeywordsResponse> xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
  <ack>Success</ack>
  <version>1.12.0</version>
  <timestamp>2013-09-03T01:10:07.967Z</timestamp>
  <searchResult count="100">
    <item>
      <itemId>231044911361</itemId>
      <title>3 X SNAKE REPELLER SOLAR POWER ULTRA SONIC LED PEST RODENT MULTI PULSE REPELLANT</title>
    </item>

</searchResult>
  <paginationOutput>
    <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
    <entriesPerPage>100</entriesPerPage>
    <totalPages>3</totalPages>
    <totalEntries>270</totalEntries>
  </paginationOutput>
  <itemSearchURL>http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_nkw=snake+repeller&amp;_ddo=1&amp;_ipg=100&amp;_pgn=1</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsByKeywordsResponse>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
    <timestamp>2013-09-03T01:10:07.967Z</timestamp>
    <searchResult count="100">
        <item>
            <itemId>231044911361</itemId>
            <title>3 X SNAKE REPELLER SOLAR POWER ULTRA SONIC LED PEST RODENT MULTI PULSE REPELLANT</title>
        </item>
    </searchResult>
    <paginationOutput>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
        <entriesPerPage>100</entriesPerPage>
        <totalPages>3</totalPages>
        <totalEntries>270</totalEntries>
    </paginationOutput>
    <itemSearchURL>http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_nkw=snake+repeller&amp;_ddo=1&amp;_ipg=100&amp;_pgn=1</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsByKeywordsResponse>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services')
SELECT itemId = t.c.value('itemId[1]', 'BIGINT')
FROM @XML.nodes('/findItemsByKeywordsResponse/searchResult/item') t(c)
```

Output -

[image: tt]

Comment: Although the answer has been accepted it is quite useful to put some kind of explanation as to what you have done to correct the problem. Yes this helps the current user with this exact scenario, but unless someone else has the exact same XML it is unlikely to benefit anyone else that views this question. E.g. without the other answer the user may not have noticed the case issue. Much like the old saying, *Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.*

Answer (score 3):

XML is case-sensitive. Replace `/SearchResult/` with `/searchResult/`.